# Is there a way in Linux to determine FOR SURE which shell executable file is running a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

Running a shell script file marked as executable results in creating a system process executing it.

It appears to me that it is not possible to determine from within the script if the executable of the interpreter used to run the script is the executable ASSUMED to be used as interpreter.

There are ways to query some data from within the script, but if an alien executable also provides them knowing that they should be there available for queries, there is no way to know if the script is run by the assumed executable or by the alien one which somehow found a way to become executed instead.

Is there a way in Linux to determine FOR SURE which shell executable file is running a shell script?

Or is it necessary to modify the source code of the interpreter in a way which makes it then possible by the scripts to be sure they are run by the interpreter executable they were designed to be run with?

I would like to gain some deeper understanding of how a Linux system works under the hood - this is the reason why do I want to get an answer to this question in hope it would help me on the way to better understanding of the system I am using.

My question IS NOT a duplicate of [How do I tell what type my shell is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166657/how-do-i-tell-what-type-my-shell-is) . I know how to ask in script which shell is running it. My question is about identifying FOR SURE which executable FILE was used in loading it to memory in order to execute the script file?

And the case of dash or bash depending on shebang in the script mentioned by me in the comments was only a trigger which started me on the path to deeper understanding. In between seems obvious to me that relying on usage of the in shebang put information is a bad idea ... it depends ... so better not rely on it at all.

Below a shell script demonstrating that it is not a good idea to ask about the shell running a script by checking the $0 or $SHELL variables or the parent process from within the script. In addition it provides evidence that the in the answer provided way gives the right executable (in dash there is no `extglob`):

```bash
o@s:~/oOo/o$ ./_oo--shPrgLang--_O--determineTheInterpreterExecutable--_oo0.sh
#!/usr/bin/dash
cat $0
pid=$$          # PID of the process invoked by THIS script 
ppid=$PPID      # PID of the parent process of the process invoked by THIS script
printf "THIS process:   ";  ps -p $pid  -o comm=
printf "PARENT process: " ; ps -p $ppid -o comm=
echo "The shell running this script is: $0  (or '$SHELL')"
printf "The executable running THIS is:     "; ls -l /proc/$$/exe
shopt -s extglob
# ======================================================
THIS process:   _oo--shPrgLang-
PARENT process: bash
The shell running this script is:   ./_oo--shPrgLang--_O--determineTheInterpreterExecutable--_oo0.sh  (or '/bin/bash')
The executable running THIS is:     lrwxrwxrwx 1 o o 0 Feb 26 16:43 /proc/67070/exe -> /usr/bin/dash
./_oo--shPrgLang--_O--determineTheInterpreterExecutable--_oo0.sh: 9: shopt: not found
o@s:~/oOo/o$ ./_oo--shPrgLang--_O--determineTheInterpreterExecutable--_oo0.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
cat $0
pid=$$          # PID of the process invoked by THIS script 
ppid=$PPID      # PID of the parent process of the process invoked by THIS script
printf "THIS process:   ";  ps -p $pid  -o comm=
printf "PARENT process: " ; ps -p $ppid -o comm=
echo "The shell running this script is: $0  (or '$SHELL')"
printf "The executable running THIS is:     "; ls -l /proc/$$/exe
shopt -s extglob
# ======================================================
THIS process:   _oo--shPrgLang-
PARENT process: bash
The shell running this script is:   ./_oo--shPrgLang--_O--determineTheInterpreterExecutable--_oo0.sh  (or '/bin/bash')
The executable running THIS is:     lrwxrwxrwx 1 o o 0 Feb 26 16:44 /proc/67075/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
o@s:~/oOo/o$ echo $0
/bin/bash
o@s:~/oOo/o$
```

Comment: The interpreter is in full control of the script, so this is a theoretical impossibility. Please update your question to explain _why_ you need this. It might be an XY problem.

Comment: What sense would it make to modify the interpreter, if you fear it might be replaced?

Comment: if `#!/bin/bash` (for example) gets replaced by a bad-actor, you've got other troubles! Good luck.

Comment: @Thomas : injecting a custom function into the source code of the interpreter which then is used to run it from the script can make it maybe harder for the alien executable which would need then to be smart enough to run the function by the genuine executable - a case an alien executable might had not covered ... but if it has ... very hard to believe that there is in fact no way to know which files are actually run on a system, isn't it?

Comment: @KlausD. : my current case is not a malicious alien interpreter run in place of bash, but the fact that it seems not to matter which shebang I am using - the script marked executable is always run by bash even if the shebang requires dash  ... This way I started to think about the mechanisms involved and on that way bumped into something I probably don't understand yet about the way Linux works.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166657/how-do-i-tell-what-type-my-shell-is ? `that it seems not to matter which shebang I am using` You created a post about how to determine the interpreter. Is this XY question? Why not ask, _why_ your script with a dash shebang is executed with bash? `is always run by bash` If you type `bash ./script` it will always be run with bash. If you type `./script`, then shebang matters.

Comment: what distro are you testing with? Did you confirm `bash` is not aliased to `dash`?

Comment: @KamilCuk : if I run the script with dash shebang using `./script` it is run by bash, if I run it with `dash script` it would be run by dash, but ... this is not my question as I am aware that I am not understanding how the interpreter is chosen to run a script by some default mechanisms. I can solve the problem by running the scripts preceding them with the right interpreter, so this is easily solved. What I am after is to UNDERSTAND if it is possible by a script to "know" if it is run by the interpreter it is designed for, and if not to exit and notify about this.

Comment: How do you know it is run by bash or dash? Please post an MCVE. I think dash is hard to detect, no? `how the interpreter is chosen` I actually described the mechanisms here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61978350/difference-between-shebang-flags-vs-set-builtin-flags/61978606#61978606 . You can run `strace bash -c './script'` and confirm what exactly bash does. Also, to "know" which interpreter is used, I posted the duplicate question, which mentions `ls -l /proc/<pid>/exe` (ach, surprisingly it is the least voted answer).

Comment: @Ron : it is not that important for me to know about the details of all the possible cases why bash is run instead of dash as I know a workaround by preceding the script with the name of the right executable. I want to make things easy - if there is a way I can know for sure how to run a script with the proper interpreter I will use it skipping that way the effort needed to understand why it doesn't in other case. There a infinite ways to go wrong, but only a few to make it right ...

Comment: @KamilCuk : I appreciate your support much, but the issue with bash or dash is not what I am actually asking for. It was only the trigger to start the desire of understanding if it is generally possible to know which exactly executable file I am actually run a script with - best it's full path name - queried from within the script itself. Probably not possible - but I am not sure. It even does not really matter for me if it is a shell script or another script (Python, Lua, ...) ... but to make things easier I have limited my question to shell scripts.

Comment: `which exactly executable file` Yes, use `ls -l /proc/$$/exe`.

Comment: Find out the PPID and look up the path to the executable. Of course, it could still be lying.

Comment: @KamilCuk : may you elaborate a bit what `ls -l /proc/$$/exe` does and why?

Comment: `what ls -l /proc/$$/exe does and why?` First shell expands the string `/proc/$$/exe` into string `/proc/<the actual process id>/exe`. Then shell executes command `ls` with two arguments `-l` and the result of the expansion. Then command `ls` prints the path in human readable format in the terminal. See `man bash` and `man ls`.

Comment: @KamilCuk : the "magic" are mechanisms behind creating and updating the `/proc/theProcessID/exe`, right? The $$ is known to the shell executing the command as the shell originates the request for creating a new process ... and then the OS takes over taking care of the appropriate entries in /proc/ directory listing all process IDs starting with 1 . Can the entire process tree be reconstructed from the entries in `/proc/`? Probably yes and what Task Manager does creating the tree of processes, right?

Comment: Yes. Typically in shell, pstree is used. Tools like ps, pstree, top traverse foreach entry in proc and present the information. Proc filesystem itself is written in kernel https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/proc.html , https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/proc/base.c#L3286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way in Linux to determine FOR SURE which shell executable file is running a shell script?

The `/proc/<pid>/exe` contains currently running executable.

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 fdsafds ffdsafsa 0 Feb 26 09:38 /proc/1649518/exe -> /usr/bin/bash*
```

Note that this is *not* the shell that you are running. I can easily do `cp /bin/bash /tmp/dash` and run `/tmp/dash`, yet it will be `bash`.

Comment: if the shell is malicious, then `ls` might not run the command expected, at least when `/proc/` is being accessed, or may return faked results

Comment: I was not aware of `/proc/somePIDnumber/exe` and other in the `/proc/` directory available data and link files yet ... this answer clarifies much for me giving some deeper understanding and pointing me towards what I have to look up in order to gain some deeper understanding of the Linux machinery. I would be glad if you could add some links to your answer pointing to further reading on it. Thanks :) .

Comment: `man 5 proc` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: @KamilCuk : it's fun ... the Properties box for the directory /proc/ lists its size as: 128.0 TiB (140,737,476,694,435 bytes) ... 281718 items (268494 files, 11806 folders).

Comment: @KamilCuk :) dziekuje za pomoc  :)

Comment: @claudio Proszki

Comment: If the shell script `exec`s something, then `/proc/PID/exe` is also replaced. At that point, the shell script is gone, so this might be what you expect, but in either case it's good to be aware.

Comment: @KamilCuk Proszki i Rolki :D