# Testing project using pytest with tests from external "tests" directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a problem with that testing. I tried to find anything but all guides are about using pycharm's abilities.
So, I have a structure like this:

```
project1
|-module1.py
tests
|-test1.py
```

module1.py:

```
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b + 1
```

test_module1.py:

```
from project1.module1 import foo

def test_foo():
    assert foo(1, 1) == 3
```

While I stay in root directory (where this structure is located), how can i run testing with pytest from terminal. I really tried my best, but always was getting different errors. Most of them look like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project1'`.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Sinse this is quite a simple question, I'm not going to leave it here. I just need some help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an empty `__init__.py` into each sub directory.

```
project1
  |-__init__.py
  |-module1.py
tests
  |-__init__.py
  |-test1.py
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `project1` path into your `PYTHONPATH`

OR

use inline command: `PYTHONPATH=project1 pytest tests/`

This thread might help clarify your doubt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15317038/2022338

Comment: Would appreciate a reason for negative vote, so I could improve.

Comment: If you add 'project1' to the path you can `import module1` but not `import project1.module1`. OP wants the second import.

Comment: actually I tested the code with `project1` in `PYTHONPATH` and it runs the test successfully without complaining about any import error. That's why I came to the above conclusion. Not sure for what reason would it fail? if it can resolve the parent module in the lookup directories.