# Startup script for non bash shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, startupscript

I have a user defined shell for CLI which i had set for some users.
Is there a way to start a script for this user who has non-bash (or non-system specific) shell, while logging in.

I tried adding some code in `/etc/profile`. no luck.
I tried putting some scripts in `/etc/profile.d`. no luck.

In both the cases it is getting called for users who has only bash prompt.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Look in the documentation of the shell to see what it uses as its startup script.

Comment: What shell are they using?

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281546/what-shell-am-i-in